# How do I delete content item with all parts in Orchard?

Tags: c#, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I'm new to **Orchard CMS** and C# development.  I'm trying to create my own **News Module**.
The module injects a few MenuItems into the AdminMenu and provides functionality to manage site news.
I've created a `NewsItem` document type, which consists of `TitlePart`, `BodyPart` and my own `NewsPart`.

`NewsPart` is based on `NewsPartRecord` which holds 2 extra string fields `SourceTitle` and `SourceUrl`.

I am faced with the problem that I can't remove entirely my content items. `ContentManager.Remove(id)` just marks the item version as `latest = false` and hides it. But I don't need to store old versions and any backups for my document items. It is like a garbage in the DB.

Using the `OnRemove` event in my `NewsPartHandler` affects only the `newsPartRecord` table, and other parts like `TitlePart`, `BodyPart` and item data and versions are still present in database.

How do I fully remove `ContentItem` data?

Answer (score 3):

You don't: Orchard only does soft deletes. This way you can undelete, and revert to previous versions. It's technically possible to clean the database of deleted items, but to my knowledge nobody bothered to do it.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I read about soft deletes, but it seems strange to me as it leads to some garbage in DB. after a week of learning Orchard the whole concept seems overcomplicated to me, and looks like it designed for end users, not for developers.

Comment: Does it cause an actual problem?

Comment: it depends on type of site, in some cases may be.

Comment: I disagree with that. Orchard is IMO designed for developers, not for end users.

Comment: Though I too think that a hard delete should exist, especially to delete really old data or data of content types that don't even exist anymore.

Comment: @teran: can you be more specific? what problem would that be?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy let suppose there is a system where we have thousands of incoming documents per day and for some reasons we should delete half of them. then after few years we have millions of garbage records in DB. In case we should process data in DB (build reports or something like that) it will decrease speed. but actually in such projects we should choose other tools, not orchard.

Comment: @devqon I said "not for developers" because there are a lot of coding in custom modules to show your list of documents, you should implement controllers to List, Create, Edit, remove documents. this looks very strange to me. I think Orchard should do all of these for me, and I should only describe document structure and templates. In case I need custom document list view, I should override this, but not to write every time.

Comment: That's a supposition, from your own words. Are you in such a situation?

Comment: Although offtopic, I couldn't agree with @devqon more. If anything, Orchard is primarily designed for developers..

Answer (score 1):

Based on [ViRuSTriNiTy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35498961/547733), this handler will destroy any content item and all its part's records when anyone of them is removed:

```
public class PermanentRemoveContentHandler : ContentHandler
{
    private readonly IOrchardServices _orchardServices;

    public PermanentDeleteContentHandler(IOrchardServices orchardServices)
    {
        this._orchardServices = orchardServices;
    }

    protected override void Removed(RemoveContentContext context)
    {
        this._orchardServices.ContentManager.Destroy(context.ContentItem);
    }
}
```

Note that for custom code, you can call `IContentManager.Destroy()` instead of the usual `IContentManager.Remove()` when you want to delete everything explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IContentManager.Delete()` instead and implement `IContentHandler` which overrides `Destroyed()` to remove dependencies like part data. This should do the trick.